# Priority between two transport fleets in Anylogic for collision free movement

Tags: anylogic

I have two transport fleets A and B. These two transport fleets are moving in path guided navigation. If both transporters A and B face a colliding situation (say 1 meter apart), then transporter B should stop and transporter A should continue in the path. Once transporter A has crossed transporter B, then transporter B can continue the movement.

Transporter A should be given higher priority for movement in all the paths of the network when a collision distance arrives.

I got to know that the automatic routing algorithm does similar work but here I have to prioritize one transport fleet over other.

Edit1:
Let us take an example of one way direction path. Transporter B (low speed) is moving in the front. Transporter A (higher speed than transporter B) arrives behind transporter B in the same path. When transporter A reaches colliding distance (say 1 meter), transporter B should stop and transporter A should move forward. In real scenario, one way path has enough space for overtaking between transporters.

I want to know how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in AnyLogic: road traffic library and process modeling library (PML). For the portion of the flow that strictly follows traffic flows (e.g. no driving in the opposite direction, no cutting lanes to reverse, etc.) you can use Road Traffic library (CarMoveTo block, for example). You can set your priority rules in the network descriptor:

[image]

For the exceptional movements, use the process modeling library (MoveTo block, for example) together with space markup elements.

Bear in mind that if you use the PML, it will have no sense of dimensions (the agents might appear on top of each other).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using moveto block and a path between two nodes. The transporters are moving on the path and when collision distance is reached one transporter is given priority always and it moves ahead while the other transporter stops.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please add screenshots of your model.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go if you want to avoid low-level coding of this beahviour is to make fleet B as free-space navigation and then uncheck "Recognize all transporters" flag for fleet A (it should still be checked for B).

In case you dont want to do it - you will need to code cyclic event inside your B-type transporters which will be stopping them if there is A-transporter nearby. But that may be non-trivial/far from real behaviour.